# Adaptar tamaño de imagen a card Ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

Desarrollo una aplicación que muestra diapositivas/slides con varias imágenes, todas de diferentes dimensiones. Necesito que las imágenes se adapten al contenedor, que lo completen y que se vean iguales en ancho y alto, pero con CSS no puedo lograrlo. Les agradeceré si me pueden ayudar, envío el código que he hecho.

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let photo of images">
 <ion-col>
<ion-card class="card">
 <ion-card-header>
…………
 </ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content >
 <ion-slides>
 <ion-slide class="center_1" *ngIf="photo.numero_de_fotos > 0">
                  <img src="{{global.paso}}img/{{photo.Id_barrio}}-{{photo.Id_atraccion}}-001.jpg">
                </ion-slide>
              </ion-slides>
              <p>{{photo.resena}}</p>
            </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
 </ion-col>
 </ion-row>

***************************************************

img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: agréguela dentro de un avatar

Comment: Gracias por responder Ronaldo99, hice img dentro del avatar dentro del slide, con border-radius: 0px; las necesito cuadradas, pero me siguen apareciendo imagenes de diferente tamaño, tal vez las propiedades CSS del avatar no las pongo bien, me podrías ayudar con eso ? Muchas gracias !

Comment: Gracias por la idea, finalmente lo resolvi fácilmente!                                     ion-avatar{
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    --border-radius: 10px;
}
ion-avatar img{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;    
}